# Error when passing a delegate from actor to statless service in service fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a serice fabric actor who calls a stateless service, this is working fine.
How ever i need to pass a delegate to .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use delegates.

Your datacontracts (the arguments and return values of your service methods) must be `DataContractSerializable`, so they can be serialized and deserialized, to allow communication across machine / process boundries. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-notes-on-actor-type-serialization). And read about Data Contracts [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731923.aspx).

Comment: how to we achieve callback then?

Comment: 1. call the Actor from the service
2. use pub/sub framework to signal completion 
3. use WCF